# UserManager.FindById is slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I using this code (where context is OAuthGrantCustomExtensionContext):

```
var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
ApplicationUser appUser1 = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("My user id"); // 31 seconds to execute
ApplicationUser appUser2 = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("My user id"); // 1 milisecond to execute
```

The execution of the function FindByIdAsync takes 31 seconds on the first time. On the second execution it's takes only <1 MS. I also checked how fast is my DB by running a "SELECT... WHERE..." query - and it's really fast - <1 MS.

I also noticed in this output inside the "Output Window":

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   in System.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   in System.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   in System.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll The
>   thread 0x1598 has exited with code 0 (0x0). Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   in System.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   in System.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   in System.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.RetryLimitExceededException' in
>   EntityFramework.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT-1-131126169736320764): Loaded
>   'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework'.  Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Exception
>   thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   in System.Data.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in
>   EntityFramework.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in
>   EntityFramework.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in
>   EntityFramework.dll Exception thrown:
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' in
>   EntityFramework.dll 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT-1-131126169736320764): Loaded
>   'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-ObjectModelLayer'.  'iisexpress.exe'
>   (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT-1-131126169736320764): Loaded
>   'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework'.

The output above is collected from the time my machine executed this line:

```
ApplicationUser appUser1 = await userManager.FindByIdAsync("My user id");
```

In the other lines of code, the Output Window was *empty*. (which can explain why they was so fast).

As you can see, alot of `SqlException` are thrown while this code line. It's seems to me like a "retry" mechanism that try agian and agian to execute some logic but it failed. I woundering if this is the reason why this taking so long?

I looking for:

1. Way to see exectly what is this `SqlException`? maybe I'll fix this and this code will run faster.
2. How to fix the FindByIdAsync to make it work fast (<5 seconds) every time?

Thank you for support!

### UPDATE

I found a useful way to catch first chance exceptions. With this code:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException +=
(object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("FirstChanceException event raised in {0}: {1}", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName, e.Exception.Message);
};
```

So, I ran the code and collected the thrown exceptions. Got the following exception for 18 times:

> The server principal "XXX" is not able to access the database "master"
>   under the current security context. Database 'master' on server
>   'XXX.net' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection
>   later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide
>   them the session tracing ID of 'XXXXXXX-68E9-4FDD-9E3D-92BE27438835'.
>   Login failed for user 'XXX'.

My user is really not allowed to access the "master" table. So, it's make sense. I change my DB connection string to another user with permission to access the "master" table - and now it's working fast! (less then 3 seconds).

After giving the right permissions, I still got this exception in the log (for 7 times):

> Invalid object name 'dbo.EdmMetadata'.

Questions:

1. I don't understand why the function `FindByIdAsync` need to access the master table???
2. How to fix the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.EdmMetadata'."?

Answer (score 1):

6 years later, I am still getting similar behavior with the latest libraries for Identity and Entity-Framework. The first call to userManager.Get[Something] takes about 5 seconds; subsequent calls are 3-10 milliseconds.
Could it be that Identity is trying to check/recreate the underlying database on the first call?